# Issues while redirecting output to file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Below is my script that checks and emails whenever memory goes below 500 MB and it works perfectly if I run manually..
If I schedule it via cron - output of the below line is not getting captured to the output file.

```
ps -A -opid | sudo xargs -n1 -I{} /bin/bash -c 'echo {} $(ls /proc/{}/fd | wc -l);' >> /home/utilization.txt
```

Code

```
#!/bin/bash

ip=`ifconfig | grep -oP '(?<=inet addr:)\d+\.\d+\.\d+\d+'`

free=$(free -mt | grep Total | awk '{print $4}')

if [[ "$free" -le 500 ]]; then
    ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | head > /home/utilization.txt

   echo -e "******************************************************************" >> /home/utilization.txt
   echo -e "******************************************************************\n" >> /home/utilization.txt
   echo -e  "Current active Process and open files\n" >> /home/utilization.txt

   ps -A -opid | sudo xargs -n1 -I{} /bin/bash -c 'echo {} $(ls /proc/{}/fd | wc -l);' >> /home/utilization.txt

   file=/home/utilization.txt

   echo -e "memory is running low on $ip Available memory: $free MB" | mailx -a "$file" -s "Check memory Status" myemail@gmail.com
fi
exit 0
```

Output file if ran via cron

```
  PID  PPID CMD                         %MEM %CPU
    1     0 /sbin/init                   0.0  0.0
    2     0 [kthreadd]                   0.0  0.0
    3     2 [migration/0]                0.0  0.0
    4     2 [ksoftirqd/0]                0.0  0.0
    5     2 [stopper/0]                  0.0  0.0
    6     2 [watchdog/0]                 0.0  0.0
    7     2 [migration/1]                0.0  0.0
    8     2 [stopper/1]                  0.0  0.0
    9     2 [ksoftirqd/1]                0.0  0.0
******************************************************************
******************************************************************

Current active Process and open files
```

Output file if ran manually

```
PID  PPID CMD                         %MEM %CPU
    1     0 /sbin/init                   0.0  0.0
    2     0 [kthreadd]                   0.0  0.0
    3     2 [migration/0]                0.0  0.0
    4     2 [ksoftirqd/0]                0.0  0.0
    5     2 [stopper/0]                  0.0  0.0
    6     2 [watchdog/0]                 0.0  0.0
    7     2 [migration/1]                0.0  0.0
    8     2 [stopper/1]                  0.0  0.0
    9     2 [ksoftirqd/1]                0.0  0.0
******************************************************************
******************************************************************

Current active Process; their PIDs and the open files

PID 0
1 8
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 0
6 0
7 0
8 0
9 0
10 0
.....
....
```

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong..

Comment: Whose crontab is it in? Can the crontab user use sudo without having to provide a password?

Comment: As an aside, there are some quite unfortunate practices in this code. `xargs -I{} bash -c '...{}...'`, in particular, is often exploitable since it's substituting data directly into strings parsed as code. Not exploitable here if the values are only PIDs, but it's **much** safer to use `xargs bash -c '... "$1" ...' _` and let the substituted values be placed in argument positions **after** the code.

Comment: In terms of addressing the actual problem, I'd strongly suggest exporting stderr to a file and enabling trace logging -- `exec 2>/tmp/cron.log; PS4=':$LINENO+'; set -x` up at the top of the script will give someone trying to answer this much more to go on.

Comment: I'd also get the `sudo` out of here -- if you need privileges, run the script with them in the first place. Sudo won't work at all by default  (on many distros) when not connected with a TTY, which would be a clear explanation for why it wouldn't work from cron.

Comment: Also, in general, `echo -e` is best avoided. It's not POSIX-compliant (POSIX doesn't even *allow* options other than `-n`, so bash is actually breaking a black-letter rule rather than implementing an extension by providing it); when you need format strings interpreted, see the APPLICATION USAGE section of [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), which describes how to use `printf` for the same thing.

Comment: Anyhow, you don't need `ps` to list PIDs -- just `shopt -s extglob nullglob`, `cd /proc`, and `for pid in +([[:digit:]]); do`; much more efficient to avoid external tools, and then inside your loop you can `set -- "$pid/fd"/*; echo "Number of FDs used by PID $pid is $#"` or such to get a count with no subshell/subprocess overhead at all.

Comment: Also, instead of putting `>> utilization.txt` after each line, just put `exec >utilization.txt` at the top of the script *once*; that way **all** output will be redirected there for the rest of the script, without needing to re-open the file before every time you're going to write just a single line (and then close it at the end of that line, re-open it for the next one, etc).

Comment: @glennjackman : yes, user canuse sudo without having to provide a password.. my user cron

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Really appreciate your inputs here... Any chance you can give me the working piece of code. I know its a big ask but I'm really struggling to get it working

Comment: @Goku, it's not just a question of `NOPASSWD`, it's also a question of whether the `requiretty` flag is set in `/etc/sudoers`, and also whether any additional security mechanisms (like SELinux) are configured to prevent privilege escalation from cron jobs. The logging I suggested with `set -x` above will expose whether at least the former of those is an issue, by recording `sudo`'s stderr in your `/tmp/cron.log` (or whatever you call it).

Comment: ...and sorry, not right now; I'm about done with my futzing-around-before-buckling-down-at-work time.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : its enabled, `Defaults    requiretty`

Comment: cron jobs won't have a TTY, then, so `sudo` configured that way won't work in them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172095/discussion-between-goku-and-charles-duffy).